# openssl/evp.h file not found -- Xmpp Integration Ios

Tags: ios, openssl, xmpp

I am trying to integrate xmpp framework in my ios application but on very starting of integration i got this error in the file named as **

> **"SSCrypto.h" in vendor folder of xmpp framework**

**
Now i surfing from while ago but i am not able to find a way to get this working . Can anyone suggest where should i look or how can i find this very particular file ?

> **OPENSSL**

I am following this tutorial [Building a Jabber Client for iOS: Interface Setup](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-interface-setup/) and i also checked **

> copy item into destination folder

** 
Actually there is a file **SSCrypto.h and SSCrypto.m** in Xmpp Framework and these files importing files named as  and as neither my application nor xmpp folder contains these "**openssl**" files my app is crashing and i donot know from where to get them.

Comment: The title says "openssl/evp.h file not found..." but the question talks about "SSCrptto.h". Which is it, and what is your question?

Comment: Sorry i edited my question, try it out if you can understand my question now.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually there is a file SSCrypto.h and SSCrypto.m in Xmpp
>   Framework and these files importing files named as and as
>   neither my application nor xmpp folder contains these "openssl"
>   files ...

Try here for the OpenSSL files: https://github.com/noloader/openssl-1.0.1e-ios.

That tarball include the OpenSSL headers and multiarch library. It will work with ARMv7, ARMv7s, ARM64 and i386 simulator.

Alternately, you can download OpenSSL and build it from sources. The download is available at [OpenSSL: Source, Tarballs](https://www.openssl.org/source/).